# Android Studio : "HAXM is not installed" при уже установленном HAXM

Tags: android-studio

При создании эмулятора в Android Studio получаю ошибку "HAXM is not installed":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом в SDK Manager видно, что HAXM уже установлен:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

да и по пути "D:\Android\sdk\extras\intel" есть папка "Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager".

В чём тогда причина того, что AVD Manager не видит HAXM?

Comment: HAXM должен быть не только проинсталирован, но так же поддерживаться оборудованием (процессор с VT-x - относительно современные Intel) и виртуализация включена в BIOS компьютера/ [Инструкция](https://habrahabr.ru/company/intel/blog/146114/)

Comment: @pavlofff, до этого у меня стояла Android Studio 1.2, и в ней эмулятор запускался без проблем. Сейчас я установила Android Studio 2.3.3, и в ней при запуске эмулятора появилась описанная ошибка. Так что вряд ли проблема в оборудовании: если на старой версии эмулятор запускался, виртуализация должна быть включена.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашла [решение проблемы на англоязычном SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37363655/4898850).

Суть этого решения в том, что после установки HAXM в SDK Manager нужно распаковать архив "intelhaxm-android.exe" и вручную запустить из него "setup.exe".

После этого сообщения "HAXM is not installed" больше не видно, эмулятор в Android Studio создаётся.

Answer (score 1):

Путь к скачанному intelhaxm-android.exe:
[sdk]\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager\intelhaxm-android.exe

Comment: Уточните, чем ваш ответ отличается от отевета ТС?

Comment: [sdk]\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager\intelhaxm-android.exe -- я долго искал файл по временным директориям винды. могете только путь от моего ответа оставить )))

Answer (score 0):

Еще добавлю что в Win 7 при установке HAXM если ругается на неподписанный драйвер, установите обновления системы.